# Subtracting datetime UTC and datetime not UTC

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

From my dataframe I am trying to subtract one `datetime64[ns, UTC]` column against a `datetime64[ns]`. I believe I should normalize one of the columns and then subtract (should add UTC to the `datetime64[ns]` column or subtract UTC to the `datetime64[ns, UTC]` so afterwards I could subtract them).

```
df
estimated_delivery_time_local                  time_check
          2020-01-22 23:48:52   2020-01-22 23:48:52+00:00
          2020-01-23 00:45:05   2020-01-23 00:45:05+00:00
          2020-01-23 03:31:38   2020-01-23 03:31:38+00:00
          2020-01-23 00:19:06   2020-01-23 00:19:06+00:00
```

I want to subtract this both column so as to check wether if all values are equal to zero

Comment: What do you expect the timezone of `estimated_delivery_time` would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first start by removing the local timestamp with:

```
df['time_check'] = df['time_check'].dt.tz_localize(None)
```

Afterwards you can perform use `np.where()` to make the comparison whether the rows are equal for the columns or not.

```
df['quality_check'] = np.where(df['estimated_delivery_time_local'] == df['time_check'],0,1)
```

This will return 1 for the rows that do not match and 0 for those that do match. You can very quickly filter the rows that do not match, or perform `df['quality_check'].sum()` to know the amount of rows that do not match.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if my answer meets your question but assuming your input data is in string format like this:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'estimated_delivery_time_local':['2020-01-22 23:48:52','2020-01-23 00:45:05','2020-01-23 03:31:38','2020-01-23 00:19:06'],'time_check':['2020-01-22 23:48:52+00:00','2020-01-23 00:45:05+00:00','2020-01-23 03:31:38+00:00','2020-01-23 00:19:06+00:00']})
```

then if you make the two columns with a normalized datetime format like this:

```
import datetime from datetime

df['time_check']=[datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S+00:00') for x in  df['time_check']]

df['estimated_delivery_time_local']=[datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for x in df['estimated_delivery_time_local']]
```

in this case you should compare the two columns or the two timestamps and check if they are the same

```
df['estimated_delivery_time_local']-df['time_check']
```